# Python - Change made to class in array not saved

Tags: python, arrays, class

I've been working all day on a bit of code for a maze generation algorithm. In this snippet:

```
if nextCoords[2] == '<':
    cells[x][y].l = False
    x, y = nextCoords[0], nextCoords[1]
    cells[x][y].r = False
```

The first line of the `if` statement, `cells[x][y].l = False` executes as expected, but for some reason `cells[x][y].r = False` does not keep the change made.

Here's the full code (with some `print`s from hopeless debugging):

```
import random

class Cell():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        self.visited = False

        self.isStart = False
        self.isEnd   = False

        self.isNormal = True

        self.u = True
        self.d = True
        self.l = True
        self.r = True

def __str__(self):
    # For console applications
    return "{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}".format(
        '^' if not self.u else ' ',
        'v' if not self.d else ' ',
        '<' if not self.l else ' ',
        '>' if not self.r else ' ',
        '+' if self.isStart else '',
        '@' if self.isEnd else '',
        ' ' if self.isNormal else ''
    )

def __repr__(self):
    return self.__str__()

def mazegen(w=3, h=3, printOut=False):
    x = 0
    y = 0

    cells = [[Cell(x, y) for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)]

    stack = []

    cells[x][y].isStart = True
    cells[x][y].isNormal = False

    while True:

        allVisited = True
        for i in cells:
            for j in i:
                if not j.visited:
                    allVisited = False

        if allVisited:
            finalCell = cells[ stack[-1][0] ][ stack[-1][1] ]
            finalCell.isNormal = False
            finalCell.isEnd = True
            break

        cells[x][y].visited = True
        choices = []
        if x > 0:
            choices.append((x-1, y, '<'))
        if x < w-1:
            choices.append((x+1, y, '>'))
        if y > 0:
            choices.append((x, y-1, '^'))
        if y < h-1:
            choices.append((x, y+1, 'v'))

        betterChoices = []
        for c in choices:
            if not cells[ c[0] ][ c[1] ].visited:
                betterChoices.append(c)
        if betterChoices != []:
            nextCoords = random.choice(betterChoices)
        else:
            popped = stack.pop()
            x, y = popped[0], popped[1]
            continue


        stack.append((x, y))

        print(nextCoords[2])
        if nextCoords[2] == '^':
            cells[x][y].u = False
            print("This cell is now {}.".format(cells[x][y]))
            x, y = nextCoords[0], nextCoords[1]
            cells[x][y].d = False
            print("The next cell is {}.".format(cells[x][y]))

        if nextCoords[2] == 'v':
            cells[x][y].d = False
            print("Old: ({0}, {1})".format(x, y))
            print(cells[x][y])
            x, y = nextCoords[0], nextCoords[1]
            print("New: ({0}, {1})".format(x, y))
            print(cells[x][y])
            cells[x][y].u = False
            print(cells[x][y])

        if nextCoords[2] == '<':
            cells[x][y].l = False
            x, y = nextCoords[0], nextCoords[1]
            cells[x][y].r = False

        if nextCoords[2] == '>':
            cells[x][y].r = False
            x, y = nextCoords[0], nextCoords[1]
            cells[x][y].l = False

        print("Moved {}\n".format(nextCoords[2]))

    if printOut:
        for i in cells:
            for j in i:
                print("| ", end='')
                print(j, end=' | ')
            print()
            print("----------"*w)

    return cells
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What *exactly* is the behavior you are seeing that you didn't expect? Is all this code really necessary to demonstrate it?

Comment: I see that when I change a value of an array element, the change doesn't stick, as if the line was never entered. *edit: but strangely, another statement doing the same thing works.

Comment: That is not nearly specific/explicit enough. *Show me what you mean*. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: first of all you need `cells = [[Cell(x, y) for y in range(h)] for x in range(w)]` if you want to do `cells[x][y]` and indent your `__str__` and `__repr__` methods into the class

Comment: I indented those properly, Stack Overflow was being weird and I didn't feel like indenting those. Changing the `cells` declaration does absolutely nothing.

Comment: i've made maze generators myself. i would recommend you try implementing it with pygame. the algorithm is to just keep moving out in random directions, any time you make a turn, you mark that corner, so eventually when you dead end yourself, you can go back to a previous corner and look for more routes. when there's no more previous corners, you're done.

Comment: @Puddle That's what I already did, using that same algorithm, but the display is weird because of the problem that this post is about.

Comment: can you post your pygame code? if so i'll correct it for you. use [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/)

Comment: I repeat: Everything pygame related works fine, I just need to fix the main topic here so that it can display the maze correctly. But since you're interested, [here it is](https://pastebin.com/Vm6EQrjr)

Comment: alright, i've just cleaned all that code up. now i'ma just follow through. wont be too long.

Comment: @JTurtle did my solution work for you?

Comment: oh btw, for this maze, since you've started building from the corner (0,0), is that where you intend to start? or end? in mine i started from the center, which is only if you only want 1 exit... for a 2 exit type, you'd also have to open up (0,-1) and (w-1,h) or wherever.

Comment: Works fine, although I did intend to start from (0,0). Thanks for dealing with this shitty post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after i cleaned up your [code](https://pastebin.com/Vm6EQrjr) it's now working and [looking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsRyJ.jpg) fine :]
[image]

```
import pygame, sys, random

class Cell:
    visited=isStart=isEnd=False
    u=d=l=r=isNormal=True
    def __init__(self,x,y): self.x,self.y = x,y

def mazegen(w,h):
    x,y = 0,0

    cells = [[Cell(x,y) for y in range(h)] for x in range(w)]

    stack = []

    cells[x][y].isStart = True
    cells[x][y].isNormal = False

    while True:

        allVisited = True
        for i in cells:
            for j in i:
                if not j.visited: allVisited = False

        if allVisited:
            finalCell = cells[ stack[-1][0] ][ stack[-1][1] ]
            finalCell.isNormal = False
            finalCell.isEnd = True
            break

        cells[x][y].visited = True
        choices = []
        if x>0:   choices.append((x-1, y, '<'))
        if x<w-1: choices.append((x+1, y, '>'))
        if y>0:   choices.append((x, y-1, '^'))
        if y<h-1: choices.append((x, y+1, 'v'))

        betterChoices = []
        for c in choices:
            if not cells[c[0]][c[1]].visited: betterChoices.append(c)
        if betterChoices != []:
            nextCoords = random.choice(betterChoices)
        else:
            popped = stack.pop()
            x,y = popped[0],popped[1]
            continue

        stack.append((x,y))

        if nextCoords[2] == '^':
            cells[x][y].u = False
            x,y = nextCoords[0], nextCoords[1]
            cells[x][y].d = False

        if nextCoords[2] == 'v':
            cells[x][y].d = False
            x,y = nextCoords[0], nextCoords[1]
            cells[x][y].u = False

        if nextCoords[2] == '<':
            cells[x][y].l = False
            x,y = nextCoords[0], nextCoords[1]
            cells[x][y].r = False

        if nextCoords[2] == '>':
            cells[x][y].r = False
            x,y = nextCoords[0], nextCoords[1]
            cells[x][y].l = False

    return cells


BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
RED   = (255,0,0)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
BLUE  = (0,0,255)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))
pygame.display.set_caption("Maze Generator!")

cells = mazegen(10,10)

while True:

    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT: pygame.quit(); sys.exit()
        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if key[pygame.K_LALT] and event.key==pygame.K_F4: pygame.quit(); sys.exit() # alt + f4

    screen.fill(BLUE)

    for i in cells:
        for cell in i:
            img = pygame.Surface((20,20))
            img.fill(WHITE)
            if cell.u:pygame.draw.line(img,BLACK,(0,0),(20,0))
            if cell.d: pygame.draw.line(img,BLACK,(0,20),(20,20))
            if cell.l: pygame.draw.line(img,BLACK,(0,0),(0,20))
            if cell.r: pygame.draw.line(img,BLACK,(20,0),(20,20))
            screen.blit(img,(cell.x*20, cell.y*20))

    pygame.display.flip()
```

also here's my really compact example. (i use pygame just to save it as an image. lol)

```
import pygame, random

def maze(*gs):
    gs = (gs[0]+3-gs[0]%4,gs[1]+3-gs[1]%4) # rounding grid size for cleaner presentation
    adjacent = lambda x,y: [(a,b) for a,b in ((x-2,y),(x+2,y),(x,y-2),(x,y+2)) if (a,b) not in tiles and a+1 and b+1 and a<gs[0] and b<gs[1]]
    pos = (gs[0]//2,gs[1]//2); tiles, points, direction = [pos], [], (0,0)
    for l in range(((gs[0]-1)//2)*((gs[1]-1)//2)-1): # total loops in algorithm
        adj = adjacent(*pos) # get available adjacents
        for i in points[::-1]:
            if adj: break # we have adjacents, we don't need to backtrack
            adj = adjacent(*i) # check if corner has spare adjacents
            if adj: points, pos = points[:points.index(i)], i # if so, remove corner, backtrack pos
        rand = random.choice(adj); new_dir = rand[0]-pos[0], rand[1]-pos[1] # get random dir
        if new_dir != direction and len(adj)>1: points += [pos] # corner and more adj remain
        tiles, pos, direction = tiles+[(rand[0]-new_dir[0]//2,rand[1]-new_dir[1]//2),rand], rand, new_dir # add path, move in direction
    pygame.init() # lets use pygame
    surface = pygame.Surface(gs); surface.fill((0,0,0)) # create black image
    for i in tiles: surface.set_at(i,(255,255,255)) # add white path
    pygame.image.save(surface,"maze.png") # save as png

maze(100,100) # create 100x100 pixel maze
```

Comment: so.... you were right about switching x and y from the start, I don't know how I thought that did nothing.

Comment: i understand you knew the loops were the same length (since w,h were square) but the variable list scopes you were using weren't. you were putting putting [y][x] equal to Cell(x,y). so they weren't being referenced correctly.